# Using visible light to get (weak) diffraction information about crystals?

Tags: laser, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

If a crystal has diameter roughly 0.25mm containing unit cells (say cubes) of about 1 angstrom on a side, there are about 2.5 million unit cells in the diameter of the crystal. Bragg's law (n$\lambda = 2d\sin\theta)$ applies, and tells us that we would like to use wavelength on the order of 1 angstrom to probe the crystal.

But if $\lambda = 5000$ angstroms (a laser) it seems we could still get refraction of parallel waves separated by about 2500 angstroms, or about $0.25$mm/$2500$ angstrom $= 1000$ reinforcing refractions in the above crystal, considering only the one dimension. Hence my question--

Is it possible that while we cannot resolve structures smaller than a few angstroms without using x-rays, we might get information (albeit attenuated) about identical repeating structures (crystals) using longer wavelengths?

Edit:

The images below may help clarify. Above is radial average intensity calculated in python for the laser diffraction of zircon image (below, with central beam edited out). One one hand I wouldn't try to correlate the calculation with XRD calculations, on the other hand there seems to be some non-random information in the image. If nothing else, this may clarify my misconceptions.

[image: attached images]

Edit 2

Am adding the

[image: unedited photo] of ZrO2.

unedited photo of ZrO2.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128954/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-using-visible-light-to-get-weak-diffraction-i).

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/661750/diffraction-conundrum is the question I asked about this conundrum.

Comment: To clarify: *in theory* a perfect crystal contains much larger identical subunits--say 5000 unit cells in diameter-- which could interact with longer light wavelengths. So Bragg's relation applies and we get what might be called 5000th order effects. In practice I think there are no effects and there is something wrong with the assumptions.

Comment: Based on the answer below it is likely the photo is of reflection, not diffraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following isn't really an answer, rather a rebuttal of sorts.

> Using visible light to get (weak) diffraction information about
> crystals

would of course a very interesting thing to do, which is why as a chemist it piqued my attention. But I fear that in accordance with common perception it isn't really possible and that which is on display in the question is something else.

I first ran a quick test with a monocrystalline [Calcite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcite#Optical) crystal, about the size of my thumb. I shone a $532\mathrm{nm}$ ($8000\mathrm{mW}$) green pointer laser through it and obtained two weakened central beams and a completely random 'halo' of scattered light. *No diffraction pattern whatsoever.*

I then finely ground up some kitchen salt (chemically $\text{NaCl}$) in a mortar and pestle and loaded it into a glass capillary tube.

But trying to shine a laser beam through that is a waste of time: like most bulk transparent materials (glass, sucrose crystals, salt crystals etc) their ground up versions simply aren't transparent to VIS.

They would be to X-rays but that would yield *circular diffraction patterns*. Only monocrystallin materials would show the kind of diffraction pattern the OP shows in his question.

So I don't know what's causing the interesting pattern but I don't think it is diffraction related. But I'd like to know more about the OP's experimental set up to understand what might be producing the observed effect.

Comment: Thanks for your upvote. Look again at Bragg's Law ($\lambda  =2d\sin\theta$ for first order spectra) and it's obvious you need rays with pretty small wavelengths to resolve lattices in the order of $0.3\mathrm{nm}$... Pity, really!

Comment: I did this experiment years ago:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384086/unusual-shape-of-maxima-in-one-slit-experiment, which shows it can't only be a case of $d/ \lambda$ ratio.

Comment: And it can't just be about energy either: a VIS laser effortlessly travels through a solid $\text{NaCl}$ crystal. I might raise a ticket myself, intrigued as I am now...